# download file with custom folder path but generated file name

Tags: python

I am downloading a file like so

```
downloadurl = "www.site.com/my_link"

urllib.request.urlretrieve(downloadurl, "/root/watch/0.txt")
```

However, I would like to download the file to a specific folder but have the file name be generated from the link (like the file name if I entered the download url in a web browser and the file name is automatically generated.  Is this possible in python?

I cannot parse the link as the file name is not present in the link.

Answer (score 0):

If `downloadurl` contains filename in last url section you can do like this:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(downloadurl, "/root/watch/" + downloadurl[downloadurl.rindex("/") + 1:])
```

Comment: The url does not contain any part of the actual file name downloaded.